# Grub error on second disk drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive

I have 2 hard disks on my laptop (a normal one in the normal slot, and a SSD one in the cd/dvd rom slot using a caddy adapter). I have Ubuntu 16.04 on the first disk and I can boot fine from it and another Ubuntu version on the second disk which I just installed.

I ran grub-update on my first Ubuntu install (on the first disk) and it shows the second disk drive install too as an entry.

The issue is that when I restart and want to get into the second Ubuntu install it errors out with a bunch of messages like:

```
no such device ID
hd1 cannot get c/h/s values
you need to load the kernel first
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try boot-repair yet?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Of course. The issue I strongly think is bios/hardware as the second drive don't appear in bios but it appears in ubuntu ?!

Comment: Perhaps but not too sure. You know many DVD caddies are only SATA I or SATA II bus? Which would be a disservice to a SATA III SSD...